# Is there any relation beetwen justification logic and type theory?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, types

[Justification logics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/), was introduced by Sergei Artemov, are epistemic logics which allow knowledge and belief modalities to be ‘unfolded’ into justification terms: instead of □X one writes t:X, and reads it as “X is justified by reason t”. Justification logic originated as part of a successful project to provide a constructive semantics for intuitionistic logic—justification terms abstracted away all but the most basic features of mathematical proofs.

The [theory of types](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) was introduced by Russell in order to cope with some contradictions he found in his account of set theory. In a system of type theory, each term has a type and operations are restricted to terms of a certain type. A typing judgment M:t describes that the term M has type t. For example, nat may be a type representing the natural numbers and 0, 1, 2, ... may be inhabitants of that type. The judgement that 2 has type nat is written as 2:nat.

It seems to me Artemov works in justification logic is similar to Russell works in type theory. Is there any evidence that there is a relation beetwen these two works?

Comment: R&W's [Principia Mathematica](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) is a "landmark work in formal logic" and it has introduced *Type Theory*; thus it can be said that it is one of the "sources" of modern math log. Apart from this, I do not see any specific link with Justification Logic.

Comment: The similarity also reminds me of the [Curry-Howard correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence): types are identified with logical propositions.  Inhabitants of a type then become proofs of the proposition.

Answer (score 2):

The evidence for a genuine relatedness is that the most influential inheritor of Russell's theory of types is Martin-Löf Type Theory which is also intrinsically connected to intuitionistic and constructive logic and mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

The article quoted points out that justification logics were invented to:

> provide constructive semantics to intuitionistic logic

And that

> proofs are justifications in their purest forms

As a comment above points out this is reminiscent of the Curry-Howard  Correspondance between types and propositions in intuitionistic logic.

This Correspondance shows that propositions in logic can be interpreted as a type; and where a type is inhabited, ie there is a term of that type, means that there is a proof for that proposition.

So, I would say yes.